# Disable all Joomla 3.0 inline styling

Tags: css, joomla, joomla-extensions, joomla3.0

I need to disable all joomla inline styling for everything.

My query isn't in regards to the text editor. 
I have no use at all for inline styling in the majority of scenarios.

It really holds me back especially on a current project with a custom template.

Any solutions? or plugins? (i have searched)

Comment: Maybe adding some jquery code to the main template ?

Comment: I'm aware I can do that as well as overriding [style] via css. But I would prefer a cleaner solution.

Comment: Where are you seeing inline style, I thought Joomla 3.1 core didn't have any inline styles.

Comment: I built templates with no styles. The layout is fluid, and everything fits to screen & on resize.

Then i populated the site with content (text & images). And the header titles & other parts external to the article contents seem to have inline styling. And it's a nightmare with text editors.

So I need a backend/ cms solution, JS won't cut it.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that this will remove the inline "style" attributes from all elements:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($){
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $(this).find("*").removeAttr("style");
    });
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

To be absolutely effective, place it just before the `</body>` tag, just in case you may have any other jQuery scripts adding css("something") to the elements.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple plugin you can run and use to find which elements contain which properties, for instance, class, style, title, width, etc.
Fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/SyFum/2/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function ($) {
        $( document ).ready( function () {

            /**
             * Highlight all elements that contain an attribute
             * @param attributeToSearch string The attribute to be found
             * @returns {*} The elements, containing the attribute, bordered
             */
            $.fn.StyleHighlighter = function (attributeToSearch) {
                // set the defaults
                var defaults = {
                    attributeToSearch : "style"
                };

                $( this ).find( "*" ).each( function () {

                    if ($( this ).attr( attributeToSearch ))
                    {
                        $( this ).css( "border", "1px dashed #ff0000" );
                    }
                } );
                return this;
            };

            // Usage (style, class, title, whatever)
            $( this ).StyleHighlighter( "style" );
        } );
    })( jQuery );
    </script>
```